# Rebrand Jaspersoft server community edition

Tags: jasperserver

Is it possible to rebrand the Jasperreports server community edition ?

I tried and i can see that i can change the titles, etc. defined in the *messages*.properties files. But, i couldnot locate the logo image which is on the header bar ( top left corner ). Whereas, I can locate the logo  image for a jasperreports-pro version. And, there is also a document on Rebranding Pro version.

Does that mean Community edition cannot be rebranded ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the logo under the themes folder. And, found the way to define a new theme folder and add my own logo and css under it.

But, a new question is that is there an elegant and quick way to add themes per organization at runtime, if the requirement is that there may be many organizations which will added every week.